# Waiting long time in execution of loop when using dynamic schedule

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am working on a project where I have to create a parallel for loop an a matrix multiplication. The code consist of 3 public variables A,B,C where A,B are the values of the arrays which I will multiply together and the variable C is the array where the results are. When am using static scheduling the execution time is normal in seconds for example

```
threads | Average (time)
  1     |    89 (sec)
  2     |    58 (Sec)
  3     |    49 (sec)
  4     |    42 (sec)
```

But when I am using dynamic sheduling  am waiting a long time in the execution for example with 4 threads I have those results , thing about the average time with less threads.

```
threads    | Average (time)
   4       |   289(sec)
```

So my question  is , is it normal with dynamic schedule this average time ? If its not how could I make it faster or better. Its important to mention that in the code below when i was trying to parallel the first or the second loop i had  logical average times with dynamic scheduling, why is this happening here ?
Explaination of my though in the code. Am using critical sections there because threads are updating the same possitions of the array.

**CODE**

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) // loop1
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) // loop2 
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for  num_threads(NUM_THREADS) \
                      schedule(static) reduction(+:sum) firstprivate(i,j)
            for (k = sum = 0; k < N; k++) // loop3
                sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            #pragma omp critical
            C[i][j] = sum;
        };
```

I know that i can overlook sum and use C[i][j] in its place but i have to keep the code like this. So can anyone tell me if i can make this better or if those times in dynamic schedule are right in the third loop

OS : linux  
cores : 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR :** The problem comes from the *dynamic* scheduler implicit synchronization that leads to thread contention.

---

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) // loop1
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) // loop2 
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for  num_threads(NUM_THREADS) \
                      schedule(static) reduction(+:sum) firstprivate(i,j)
            for (k = sum = 0; k < N; k++) // loop3
                sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            #pragma omp critical
            C[i][j] = sum;
        };
```

As I have mentioned in your previous question probably it would have been more efficient to parallelize the outermost loop instead.

> Am using critical sections there because threads are updating the same
> possitions of the array.

In your current version you can remove that `#pragma omp critical` is not doing anything since it is outside the parallel region. Hence, the code is being executed sequentially.

> So my question is , is it normal with dynamic schedule this average
> time ?

The *dynamic* scheduler is more appropriate when there are load-balancing issues, *i.e.,* threads performing more work than others, which is not your case. In your code, threads perform roughly the same amount of work. The downside of the *dynamic* scheduler, however, is that it adds an extra synchronization overhead, needed to atomically distribute the iterations among the threads.

> If its not how could I make it faster or better.

For your case the *static* scheduler is the most appropriate. Nonetheless, you can reduce the overhead of the dynamic scheduler by increasing the chunk size used (*e.g.,* 32 instead of the default 1). By increasing the chunk size you will reduce (among others) the amount of synchronization used and hence also reduce its overhead.

> Its important to mention that in the code below when i was trying to
> parallel the first or the second loop i had logical average times with
> dynamic scheduling, why is this happening here ?

Because *before* the granularity of the parallel tasks was greater (*i.e.,* each parallel task took more time to be executed). With the current parallelization, the task granularity is *too small*. It is too small because you are only performing `sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];` and because the chunk size of the *dynamic* scheduler is just one, which means threads will call the *dynamic* scheduler too often. And since the *dynamic* synchronizes, that synchronization can introduce thread contention, which occurs when two or more threads try to access the same resource simultaneously. And that is why you have such a slowdown with 4 threads; because in the aforementioned conditions the higher the number of threads, the higher will be the likelihood of having thread contention.

As pointed out in the comments (to this answer) by [Jim Cownie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900441/jim-cownie)

> One minor additional fact to know about is that if you're using an up
> top date (i.e. OpenMP 4.5 or later) compliant compiler you can use
> schedule(nonmonotonic:dynamic) which can significantly reduce the
> overhead of schedule(dynamic)
> openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/SC18-BoothTalks-Cownie.pdf